# Joining byte list with python

Tags: python, list, join, byte

I'm trying to develop a tool that read a binary file, makes some changes and save it. What I'm trying to do is make a list of each line in the file, work with several lines and then join the list again.

This is what I tried:

```
file = open('myFile.exe', 'r+b')

aList = []
for line in f:
    aList.append(line)

#Here im going to mutate some lines.

new_file = ''.join(aList)
```

and give me this error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

which makes sense because I'm working with bytes.

Is there a way I can use join function o something similar to join bytes?
Thank you.

Comment: for what it's worth, you could do `aList = f.readlines()` or `aList = list(f)`

Comment: Try: `new_file = '\x01'.join(aList)`

Comment: Does it make sense to talk about "lines" in a binary file? Usually we add newlines for legibility, and that doesn't apply to binary files. I wonder if you'd be better off working with fixed-length strings, like every 80 bytes. (Just a thought.)

Comment: @sea-rob PDFs for example are a weird mishmash of text and binary format, where sometimes line breaks matter and you can have bytes that don't form valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Perform the join on a byte string using `b''.join()`:

```
>>> b''.join([b'line 1\n', b'line 2\n'])
b'line 1\nline 2\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just work on your "lines" and write them out as soon as you are finished with them.

```
file = open('myFile.exe', 'r+b')
outfile = open('myOutfile.exe', 'wb')

for line in f:
    #Here you are going to mutate the CURRENT line.
    outfile.write(line)
file.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: I didn't think about this solution, this is much easier than mine. Thanks!