# Saving input fragments into a list by index and merging them

Tags: python, list, sockets, udp

I am sending message from one PC to other PC over UDP with my own header. User can set size of fragment for the message what means that I have to divide message into fragments and send them over to other PC, what should work in my code (did not test because receiving is the problem).

Now, on the receiver side, I need to keep track of fragment index, total fragment number and some other things which are defined in my header to check for possible data loss like (CRC). But let's get back to the problem.

I am saving every received fragment pieces by it's index into a `list`. So let's say `index` of first fragment in header is `1`, so I want to save first fragment on position `1`. I keep doing this in a while cycle until I get last data fragment. But something doesn't work properly. At the end, I want to print out my received message in order as it was saved in the list, from `index` `1` until the end using `''.join(list)`.

Check out my code, it is either printing out the message divided into fragments or when I move out the `print` of `while` cycle, then it prints nothing, not even the `Receive:` message.

Sending:

```
def send_loop(self):
    global mType, fragSize, fragIndex, fragCount, crc
    mType=0
    fragSize=0
    fragIndex=0 
    fragCount=0 
    crc=0
    fragSize = int(input('Fragment size: ')) #max size of fragment
while True:
            message = input('Enter message: ')
    #sending text message
            if (message[:2] == '-m'):
                mType = 1 #text message
                if message.startswith('-m '):
                    message = message[3:] # remove "-m "
                fragCount = math.ceil(len(message) / fragSize)  #rounding up number of fragments to send

                while message!= '':
                    data = bytearray()
                    data.extend(message[:fragSize].encode('utf-8'))
                    fragIndex += 1
                    header = struct.pack('!hIIII', mType, fragSize, fragIndex, fragCount, crc)
                    self.sock.sendto(header + bytearray(data), (self.host, self.port))
                    message = message[fragSize:] #set start of message to the right by size of fragSize
```

Receiving:

```
def create_socket(self):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        rec_list = []
        while True:
            data, addr = sock.recvfrom(65535)
            header = data[:18]
            data = data[18:]
            (mType, fragSize, fragIndex, fragCount, crc) = struct.unpack('!hIIII', header)

        #type of message is text
            if mType == 1:
                if len(rec_list) < fragCount:
                    rec_list = ['None'] * fragCount   #empty list for messages of size fragCount
                rec_list[fragIndex] = data.decode('utf-8') 


                print(
                    '\nTyp: '       + str(mType) + 
                    '\nFragSize: '  + str(fragSize) + 
                    '\nFragIndex: ' + str(fragIndex) + 
                    '\nFragCount: ' + str(fragCount) + 
                    '\nCRC: '       + str(crc)
                    )
                msg = ''.join(rec_list)
                print('\nReceived: ' +  msg)
```

Comment: We would need to see the sending code also.

Comment: @JohnGordon updated

Comment: The `while True` is fine to keep your socket listening, however, you need to know when you're done receiving the data, right? It _seems_ to me that there's a condition (or another nested `while` loop) missing somewhere? Also, keep in mind that when you do `rec_list = ['None'] * fragCount`, you're destroying any information that you might have already extracted into `rec_list` from a previous package, right?

Comment: @BorrajaX I will look at the `while True` because it seems okay to me for now but about the `rec_list = ['None'] ` yes I know that it can destroy previous information and I need to fix it also, because I can send a message after another and it will keep rewriting the `list`, but I haven't figured out how should I do it. Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... Below you'll find some code that keeps listening (in the first `while True`) forever. What I added is the second `while` loop. When you receive something, you need to enter into "rebuild" mode (into the second loop) and continue being there until all the chunks that conform your message are received.

Since the total number of chunks that you need to rebuild the full message is sent in every package, you can use that information to know how many pieces you're going to need in order to rebuild the message. Every time you receive a package, that means you've received one chunk (and that information is kept in the `received_chunks` variable).

Once you have received the same number of chunks as the number of total chunks, you know that you have rebuild your message, and you can exit the inner `while` to continue listening for the next message.

Note that I'm also *extending* the `rec_list` if it's smaller than the total number of fragments that conform the message. You probably don't need that, because right before getting into the inner loop it's initialized to an empty list. In the inner loop, you could substitute this:

```
if len(rec_list) < fragCount:
    need_to_add = fragCount - len(rec_list)
    rec_list.extend([None] * need_to_add)
```

By this:

```
if not rec_list:
    rec_list = [None] * fragCount
```

I did it like this to avoid deviating too much from the code. There's more cleanup you can do. I'd recommend doing more `print(`s to see the status of the different variables and what's happening...

```
while True:
    received_chunks = 0
    rec_list = []
    # Let's start receiving chunks...
    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(65535)
        header = data[:18]
        data = data[18:]
        (mType, fragSize, fragIndex, fragCount, crc) = struct.unpack('!hIIII', header)
        print(
            '\nTyp: ' + str(mType) +
            '\nFragSize: ' + str(fragSize) +
            '\nFragIndex: ' + str(fragIndex) +
            '\nFragCount: ' + str(fragCount) +
            '\nCRC: ' + str(crc)
        )
        # type of message is text
        if mType == 1:
            if len(rec_list) < fragCount:
                need_to_add = fragCount - len(rec_list)
                rec_list.extend([None] * need_to_add)  # empty list for messages of size fragCount
            rec_list[fragIndex - 1] = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("We have received %s chunks. We expect a total of %s."
              " We are awaiting for %s chunks"
              % (received_chunks, fragCount, fragCount - received_chunks))
        received_chunks += 1
        if received_chunks == fragCount:
            break  # Get out of the second loop because we have all the chunks that we need.

        print("rec_list so far=%s" % (rec_list))
    # This is where the second (inner) while loop ends.

    print("Yay!! We got a FULL message...")
    msg = ''.join(rec_list)
    print('\nReceived: ' + msg)
```

Comment: I tried it but when I send first message, it prints out nice all together but when I write second message after the first one, then I get error `rec_list[fragIndex-1] = data.decode('utf-8')
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
`

Comment: Oh! Your sender script is accepting things like `python sender_script.py -m foo -m bar"` ?

Comment: **If that's the case**, I think your problem is in the `sender_script`... When you do `message = message[3:]` in it, `message` will be `foo -m bar`?

Comment: No, no. `message=message[3:]` is cutting the `-m` so the length of the message becomes clean message which is followed after `-m `

Comment: What are you sending in the part that sends data? Some other type besides a `-m` message? (a text message?)

Comment: I'm asking because if I launch the sender in another terminal, and I keep doing... `-m foo` (+enter), the receiver does receive `foo`. If after that I type `-m foobar`, the receiver does receive `foobar`... I can't reproduce that behavior **:-S**

Comment: The message is something like this: `-m Hello world!` The `-m` is only a switch for message type, because I am also going to send files. And I think the problem is in the `if not rec_list:
                        rec_list = [''] * fragCount` because it looks like it doesn't empty the `list`, it skips the condition and goes to the index which is not empty I guess. Or?

Comment: The idea of doing that is not exactly emptying the list but rather create a new list with `fragCount` elements (all initialized in that case to empty string)... I just changed my test code to what you mention in the comment, and it's sill working fine on my end? This is odd...

Comment: Wait, have you added the two lines on my example: `received_chunks = 0
    rec_list = []` right below the first `while loop`? Because once you receive (and _rebuild_) a message, you need to "reset" the count of received chunks and the list where you're storing the chunks.

Comment: I have those two lines just like you have after first `while True`, there are those two. I have no idea why it doesn't work. Do you want more code?

Comment: MmmmmHHHhhhMMMMMMMmmm... Maybe, but before that, three questions: 1) If in your sender you send `-m Hello World!`, what does the receiver print as `FragSize`, `FragIndex` and `FragCount` right before the failure? 2) What is the fragment size chosen in the sender side. 3) How is the sender called? (You mentioned `-m Hello world` in another comment... Is that all what is entered in the sender side?)

Comment: Okay, thats what I just noticed is that I send first message `-m hello` and the `fragSize` is set to `3`  `fragIndex = 2` `fragCount=2` in the final, when it is printed out, what is CORRECT! But! Right after this, I send `-m world` and the `fragSize=3`, correct, `fragIndex = 3` INCORRECT!!! `fragCount=2` correct. So there is that index flying high. And sender is also setting the `fragSize` but it is right at the start of the program, it is kinda separated from the messages.

Comment: I sounds like `fragIndex` needs to be reset to `0` in the sender, after sending the message, so every message starts over at `0` (I'd put `fragIndex=0` right after the `message = input('Enter message: ')`) What happens if you do that?

Comment: I have added some more code on the top of sender function, there are some variables declared, which might cause trouble with resetting `fragIndex`

Comment: WORKS! Just like you said, putting it after `enter message` helped! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yaaay!! Finally! **:+1:** It makes sense too, since each message is split in their own fragments, right? **:)**

Comment: Yes, I will have to do the same I guess for sending files, I hope it will work. And also, can I kind of say that it is ACK ? Because ACK is checking for correct chunk that receiver is awaiting but what my code does is that it basically saves all pieces on index and at the end checks if number of fragments equals. Question is, what if there is really one or more missing and I need to resend it from sender?

Comment: Well... If you accept another type (besides the text `-m`, you might have to move things around a bit on the code) For ACK... that's a gonna take more thinking... First of all (theoretically) you could get chunks of message "A" and of message "B" out of order right? You might need a way of identifying what message does the chunk belong to. And then... How to know that the message is incomplete? The sender might just be taking a long time? You might need to time it out? (like _"if I haven't received the full message in 10 seconds, then I timeout_") Depends a bit on what you wanna do.

Comment: Its a school assigment and it must be done in 22 hours, so I have to do it :D Is there something I could learn fast to do the ACK? Using those timeouts and stuff?

Comment: Oh ,boy... Well... If it's only 22 hours, then I wouldn't get that fancy, at least not for now... In the TCP protocol, an ACK only means that I have received **this** package. So what you can do is send back a datagram with only one field: The `fragIndex` and F it... Like ok, I got this fragment. In your sender, you could do something like `Send fragment --> Get the ACK --> No ack? Then resend fragment`

Comment: F it? I am going to try it, would be nice if we could stay in touch if I run into trouble, your explanation fits me very well. Btw, can I apply this `list` for sending files also? Because I am doing it right now and have no idea if its a good choice.

Comment: I'll try to stay in touch **:)** You can apply this idea for sending files, yeah. You just will have more chunks (probably files are much bigger than `Hello world`, which is 11 bytes) However, keep in mind that the code as it shown in my answer, all that `list` magic is under the `if mType == 1:`, so if `mType` is different than `1`, it won't apply (you might have to move the logic of the list filling outside that `if`)

Comment: Also, consider if your question about the ACK is worth opening another question (mostly because people who find this question in Google and don't read these comments might have trouble understanding the iterations over the code) Up to you, though **:-)**

Comment: If I move the filling logic out of the `if` then what will be the purpose of that `if mType == 1`? How will I separate different messages?

Comment: I'm guessing it would be more used at the end: Once you reconstruct a message, you could just `print` it on the console (if it's a string, hence `mType == 1`) or you could just save it somewhere (if it's a file with some other `mType`)

Comment: I will create new topic for ACK after I get some sleep, but now I just want to finish sending file which is causing some trouble. I cant get file to open and get sent by segments into the list.

Comment: Cool, makes sense! By the way, to fully read a file, you can call `.read()` on the file object. Take a look to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: I am thinking about sending first file name using the method of fragments and then sending content of the file. Should I use two while cycles one after another? Or what would be better?

Comment: Hmm... If you do that, then you're gonna have two separate messages (one the filename, one more the file contents) so when you receive a file, you must also have kept track of the _previous_ message and that's a bit more complex. Something you can do is reserve a number of characters for the filename (let's say... `128`) and send that before sending the contents of the file. If the filename is less than `128`, just fill it with whitespaces. That way, if in the receiver your `mType` signals a "file", you build your message, get the first `128` chars (that's the filename) and then the contents.

Comment: Thats what I thought. But when I try to read file by fragments, it gives me error `TypeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object is not subscriptable`. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you calling `file.read()` or `file[something]` (the latter will give you that error) See https://www.google.com/search?q=_io.BufferedReader%27+object+is+not+subscriptable&oq=_io.BufferedReader%27+object+is+not+subscriptable&aqs=chrome..69i57.397j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I am using `f=open(file_name,"rb")`

Comment: Then you should be able to load its contents doing `contents = f.read()` Is that giving you an error? The contents of the file should be in the `contents` variable

Comment: It looks good for now, but I can't really test it because it looks like I can't use the list for saving binary data. I am trying to send `JPG` file. Receiving part is the problem now.

Comment: You can pass the file contents through a `base64` encoder, send that, and, once you have received all the chunks, decode it in the receiver (that will convert all the "weird" characters to regular ascii) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715493/encoding-an-image-file-with-base64

Comment: Received all the chunks... And removed the first 128 characters that are actually the filename, not the file contents **;-)**

Comment: `f=open(file_name,"rb")
                contents = f.read()
                contents.encode(base64_encode)` gives me error `'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: Double check the link I pasted in the comment above. You encode the contents with `encoded_contents = base64.b64encode(contents)` (you'll need to `import base64` at the top of your `.py` file)

Comment: It might be my bad, cause I run it again with no encoding just plain `contents` with binary data I guess and it gives me error all the way in `receiver` because `join` wants a string. `content = ''.join(rec_list)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`

Comment: Looks like you're getting closer. Take a look to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068100/joining-byte-list-with-python

Comment: Basically, you need to transform from `bytes` to `str`: Something like `b''.join(rec_list).decode()`

Comment: Got it, but again previous problem with index??? Here is info of the variables: `FragSize: 1500
FragIndex: 5016
FragCount: 5015`

Comment: In the sender, are you calculating the total length (which is `file_name` + `file_contents` _before_ calculating the number of fragments?) Because the `file_name` should also count towards the total size to transmit.

Comment: Not the filename yet, I have skipped the name for now, doing just plain content

Comment: Mmm... If you're using the `base64` encoder, are you calculating the number of fragments _after_ encoding? Basically, the calculation of the number of fragments should be the last thing you do in the sender before sending...

Comment: I am not using `base64`. And yes, calculation is just before sending. I really have no idea why is it doing this. Its exactly same as with strings and it just doesn't work. Every time, `index` number is bigger by `1` then `count` number, in every file I try to send.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bit difficult for me guessing without seeing the code... Maybe it's worth it opening another question for it? (knowing how the site works, it'd be great if you could isolate in your code the file sending part, and dispose of the "regular string" sending part? ) I'm fairly sure the question will be better received that way (if there's too much code, people tend to downvote it)

Comment: Okay, check it out here please, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325616/sending-file-over-udp-divided-into-fragments