# Sending file over UDP divided into fragments

Tags: python, file, sockets, udp

I have been dealing with sending file which is divided into fragments set by user on input. Problem is, I am getting error:

`rec_list[fragIndex - 1] = data`
`IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

I am also sending single string messages like in a chat and it works normally.
I can't find a bug in my code but maybe you can.

Btw, there are variables which might help with math which doesn't fit probably.

`fragSize = 3`

`fragIndex = 216`

`fragCount = 215`

Problem is, total number of fragments should be 215 (precalculated before sending - IS OK), `index` shouldn't be more than `count`! That is the problem. And it doesn't happen with strings. Only here with file.

Sending:

```
fragSize = int(input('Fragment size: ')) #max size of fragment
        while True:
            message = input('Enter message: ')
            fragIndex=0 #reset fragment indexing

    #asking for fragment size
            if(message[:3] == '-sf'):
                fragSize = int(input('Fragment size: '))
```

And here is sending function for files:

```
if (message[:2] == '-f'):
                mType = 3
                if message.startswith('-f'):
                   message = message[3:]

                file_name = message
                f=open(file_name,"rb")
                contents = f.read()
                fragCount = math.ceil(len(contents) / fragSize)

                while contents!= '':
                    data = bytearray()
                    data.extend(contents[:fragSize])
                    fragIndex += 1
                    crc = crc32(data)
                    header = struct.pack('!hIIII', mType, fragSize, fragIndex, fragCount, crc)
                    self.sock.sendto(header + bytearray(data), (self.host, self.port))
                    contents = contents[fragSize:]
```

Receiving:

```
while True:
            received_chunks = 0
            rec_list = []
            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(65535)
                header = data[:18]
                data = data[18:]
                (mType, fragSize, fragIndex, fragCount, crc) = struct.unpack('!hIIII', header)

                print(
                '\nTyp: ' + str(mType) +
                '\nFragSize: ' + str(fragSize) +
                '\nFragIndex: ' + str(fragIndex) +
                '\nFragCount: ' + str(fragCount) +
                '\nCRC: ' + str(crc)
                )

                if len(rec_list) < fragCount:
                    need_to_add = fragCount - len(rec_list)
                    rec_list.extend([''] * need_to_add)  # empty list for messages of size fragCount
                rec_list[fragIndex - 1] = data

                received_chunks += 1
                if received_chunks == fragCount:
                    break  # This is where the second while loop ends
```

This is only if I want to receive message of type file: (because it is divided into more message types)

```
if mType == 3:
     content = b''.join(rec_list)
     f = open('filename.py','wb')
     f.write(content)
```

Comment: If in the sender you put a `print(fragCount)` right after you calculate the number of fragments (right under `fragCount = math.ceil(len(contents) / fragSize)`) what do you get?

Comment: Same number as I get in `fragCount` in the rest of program.

Comment: `fragIndex` should never be larger than `fragCount` so you could add a test in the sender's `while` loop that either breaks to a debugger or prints out data. You could also add more print traces and pick a much smaller file. If `fragCount` is 3, then maybe a file of 10 bytes would be useful.

Comment: As an aside, UDP is unreliable and if a datagram is dropped your server will hang.

Comment: I was thinking, couldn't be the `b` as `binary` problem? I mean since its a binary file, there is that extra `b` in there right? Or not? And I don't necessary need a small file, I can just set `fragSize` to big number and it will iterate very fast with small numbers. And yes I know UDP is unreliable but now, its running on my localhost so it kinda should be okay and later on, I am going to add `ACK`.

Comment: @tdelaney point is very valid. We need to narrow down the issue: Make sure that the **sender** is not sending a higher `fragIndex` than the total `fragCount` (a `print` would suffice). Plus, if you deal with smaller files, it has the advantage that you can calculate the `fragCount` "by hand". For instance, a file that is 10 bytes long (10 characters) with a `fragSize` of `3` should give a `fragCount` of 4. Is that happening?

Comment: Yes, `fragCount` is 4, but `fragIndex` is 5 of course. I'm going to add the `index` printer to check whats going on.

Comment: Aight, so the issue seem to be in the sender part.... That's good to know. Narrowed it down  **:)**

Comment: Groan time! `contents` is a `bytes` object and will never be equal to the `''` string object. Change your client to `while contents:`. As usual, "truthy" comparisons rule.

Comment: OH boy!! TIL!! `>>> b'' == '' ; False` (makes complete sense, and I should've seen it before!!) Dang!! @tdelaney, you should put that in an anwser so the OP can choose it.

Comment: Wait, what? I dont get it. Sorry, I  have only like 17 hours until deadline so I havent slept for about 26 hours. What do I have to change?

Comment: Change `while contents!= '':` to `while contents:`.

Comment: OK OK I got it! I read it like 10 times, I got it boys! THANK YOU, now I go to bed, then work on ACK. Thanks again for now, please help me tomorrow too. Deadline in 17 hours :/

Comment: @BorrajaX it wasn't until I worked up some mock tests on my side that I noticed it. My test loop wasn't stopping and it wasn't till I stepped through it that I noticed. _Then_ it was very obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to compare [apples to oranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges). Well, `bytes` to `str` but wikipedia doesn't say anything about that.

```
while contents!='':
    ...
```

`contents` is a `bytes` object and `''` is a `str` object. In python 3, those two things can never be equal. Firing up the shell we see that

```
>>> b''==''
False
>>> 
>>> contents = b"I am the very model"
>>> while contents != '':
...     if not contents:
...         print("The while didn't catch it!")
...         break
...     contents = contents[3:]
... 
The while didn't catch it!
```

Since all objects have a truthiness (that is, `bool(some_object)` is  meaningful) and `bytes` objects turn `False` when they are empty, you can just do

```
while contents:
    ....
```

*UPDATE*

Not part of the original answer but a question was raised about sending retries back to the client. The server side is sketched in here

```
while True:
            received_chunks = 0
            fragCount = -1
            rec_list = []
            while True:
                # wait forever for next conversation
                if fragCount == -1:
                    sock.settimeout(None)
                try:
                    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(65535)
                except socket.timeout:
                    # scan for blank slots in rec_list
                    retries = [i for i, data in rec_list if not data]
                    # packet is mType, numFrags, FragList
                    # TODO: I just invented 13 for retry mtype
                    sock.sendto(struct.pack("!{}h".format(len(retries+2)), 13,
                        len(retries), *retries)
                    continue
                # our first packet, set timeout for retries
                if fragCount == -1:
                    sock.settimeout(2)
                header = data[:18]
                data = data[18:]
                (mType, fragSize, fragIndex, fragCount, crc) = struct.unpack('!hIIII', header)

                print(
                '\nTyp: ' + str(mType) +
                '\nFragSize: ' + str(fragSize) +
                '\nFragIndex: ' + str(fragIndex) +
                '\nFragCount: ' + str(fragCount) +
                '\nCRC: ' + str(crc)
                )

                if len(rec_list) < fragCount:
                    need_to_add = fragCount - len(rec_list)
                    rec_list.extend([''] * need_to_add)  # empty list for messages of size fragCount
                rec_list[fragIndex - 1] = data

                received_chunks += 1
                if received_chunks == fragCount:
                    break  # This is where the second while loop ends
```

Comment: Okay, its transfering but when the fragments are delivered, I dont see the new file anywhere. It is a `.JPG` file about `8Mb` and it wont show in folder. I tried smaller file and it showed up.

Comment: If a datagram is dropped in the network, your server will hang. You could add `received_chunks` to your server trace message to see if it goes to... well, depending on where you print it... to `fragCount-1`. You could also add a `print("Waiting for file")` in the first `while` loop to let you know whether it made it out of the inner while.

Comment: Oh, and the code you show doesn't actually write the file. You have to do that part! Since small files work you must be doing that somewhere.

Comment: I just noticed `fragIndex` doesnt go one after another, it skipped some. Question, is there a simple solution so I get all of them? Or is it just using `ACK`?

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt write the file? What about the code `f = open('filename.py','wb')
     f.write(content)`

Comment: Its a difficult problem. Datagrams can come in out of order. Your code already handles that. Now you need an ACK but also a retransmit request. The client needs to keep track of fragments until they are ACK'd then can then discard them. The server could also have a timer that is reset when each frag arrives. If the timer triggers, it reports to the client all fragments it hasn't seen yet.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that fragment was part of the server script. I knew it was in there somewhere.

Comment: Yes, that timer is probably the best choice for me now, cause I am running out of time, due to the deadline (school project) as I already discussed with @BorrajaX who helped me a lot too. Any examples how to do the timer triggers?

Comment: @febeks17, the timer is probably subject for another question. One thing that comes to mind, is: Every time you start "reconstructing" a message, create a new timer (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#timer-objects) with some kind of _on\_failure_ function as callback. When you receive a chunk, cancel it and re-create it again with the same interval.

Comment: @BorrajaX and febeks - I sketched in a partial solution on the server side that fiddles with the socket timeout. Kinda primitive. There would need to be a listener on the client also.

Comment: @tdelaney so you set the `mType=13` which means I have to create `mType` in `sender` which will resend the missing socket when it receives message of `mType=13` right? If so, how do I know which packet to resend? Where do I get information about it? And I should have created new topic but since it already here, lest just finish it in here please.

Comment: I have decided to create a new topic so its nice and clear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330328/implementing-ack-in-udp-chat

Comment: @BorrajaX could you help me somehow with that ACK in the new topic? I have only few hours left and `keep alive` + `ACK` must be done and I am stuck with that ACK right now, cant even do the keep alive